# Knockout Js template not displaying data

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have the following knockout js code, for some reason, the booking.text is not displaying, see how column 1 has no text.

Can anyone advice what I have done wrong and how this can be fixed?

You can see the running code in JS Fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/w3fxtdq8/18/

[image]

Below is the code I am using

```js
var myViewModel = {
  bookings: ko.observableArray([{
      text: 'booking 1',
      bookingId: 123
    },
    {
      text: 'booking 2',
      bookingId: 123
    },
    {
      text: 'booking 3',
      bookingId: 123
    }
  ])
};
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="template: {name: 'booking-table-row-template', foreach: 'bookings', as: 'booking'}">

  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/html" id="booking-table-row-template">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: booking.text"></td>
    <td>
      <A href="#">Remove</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put quotes around a variable name. The clue is in how many rows got rendered - 8 (same as the number of letters in the word 'bookings') rather than 3 (size of your array).

You made `bookings` a string.

```js
var myViewModel = {
  bookings: ko.observableArray([{
      text: 'booking 1',
      bookingId: 123
    },
    {
      text: 'booking 2',
      bookingId: 123
    },
    {
      text: 'booking 3',
      bookingId: 123
    }
  ])
};
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="template: {name: 'booking-table-row-template', foreach: bookings, as: 'booking'}">

  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/html" id="booking-table-row-template">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: booking.text"></td>
    <td>
      <A href="#">Remove</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</script>
```